# Random word generator using python

Tags: python, random, decode

I would like to generate random words from ascii codes.
I have tried like that:

```
 import random

 liste = [random.randint(33, 127) for i in range(8)]
 osman=', '.join(str(x) for x in liste)
 a=bytes.fromhex(hex(liste[0])[2:]).decode()
 b=bytes.fromhex(hex(liste[1])[2:]).decode()
 c=bytes.fromhex(hex(liste[2])[2:]).decode()
 d=bytes.fromhex(hex(liste[3])[2:]).decode()
 e=bytes.fromhex(hex(liste[4])[2:]).decode()
 f=bytes.fromhex(hex(liste[5])[2:]).decode()
 g=bytes.fromhex(hex(liste[6])[2:]).decode()
 h=bytes.fromhex(hex(liste[7])[2:]).decode()

 print(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,sep="")
```

Is there an easier way and how can i develop for more words?

Comment: You could simply instead of `osman=', '.join(str(x) for x in liste)` write `osman=''.join(chr(x) for x in liste)` and print it. You don't need the `a` to `h` variables, thus you can discard them.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. It works.

Comment: @VasilisG. you should move that comment to an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that exactly I want to do.Thanks to Vasilis G.

```
import random
i=0
k=""
while i<100:
    i+=1    
    liste = [random.randint(97, 122) for i in range(8)]
    osman=''.join(chr(x) for x in liste)
    k+=osman+" "
print(k)
```